# How do I remove a class when I select a category?

Tags: javascript, sorting

My site has page search and category sorting (all on one page).

The problem is that when I type something in the search bar and get the result, I cannot sort by category, because I have hidden elements of the `hide` class (This is how the search works - elements that do not match are hidden.).

How do I remove the `hide` class when I click on the sort button?

If you have any questions - ask!

```js
let noResult = document.querySelector("#no-result-id");

    document.querySelector('#elastic').addEventListener("input", function() {
        let val = this.value.trim();
        let items = document.querySelectorAll('.elastic article h3');

        if (!val) {
            noResult.classList.add("hide");

            return items.forEach(function _show_all(elem) {
                elem.closest('article').classList.remove('hide');
            });
        }

        /***/

        let anyMatch = false;

        items.forEach(function(elem) {
            let isMatching = new RegExp(val, "gi").test(elem.textContent); // true или false

            anyMatch = anyMatch || isMatching; // (*)
       

            elem.closest("article").classList.toggle('hide', !isMatching);
        });

        noResult.classList.toggle("hide", anyMatch);
    });

const sortArticles = (cont, order) => {
        const container = document.getElementById(cont);
        order.forEach(idx => container.appendChild(container.querySelector("[data-custom-sort='" + idx + "']")))
    };

    document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener("click", e => {
        const tgt = e.target;
        if (tgt.classList.contains("choose-cat")) {
            e.preventDefault()
            sortArticles("game-items-cart", tgt.dataset.order.split(","))
        }
    })
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.elastic article.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="elastic" class="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search Anything Here...">

<div id="sort">
  <a id="sort-best" class="choose-cat" data-order="3,1,2">best</a> |
  <a id="sort-default" class="choose-cat" data-order="1,2,3">default</a>
</div>

<div id="game-items-cart" class="elastic">
<span id="no-result-id" class="no-result hide">no result</span>
  <article data-custom-sort="1">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">One</h3>
  </article>
  <article data-custom-sort="2">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Two</h3>
  </article>
  <article data-custom-sort="3">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Three</h3>  
  </article>


</div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML code related to this JS?

Comment: @Anton, i added HTML

Comment: I don't know how to add this fancy message that you should provide something that can be runnable... So I will just say in old fashion way :) Your HTML is not enough... because I can't run it. It is missing this elements: `#sort`, `#no-result-id`, `.elastic article h3`

Comment: It will be super if you can add not just plain code text to your question, but working "code snippet". You can insert it by pressing button `[<>]` in question edit.

Comment: @Anton, hey, thx for you comment, i updated this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Shivanshu Singh is almost working. I've just removed unnecessary code and clear search input on sort:

```js
let noResult = document.querySelector("#no-result-id");

document.querySelector('#elastic').addEventListener("input", function() {
  let val = this.value.trim();
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.elastic article h3');
  let anyMatch = false;
  items.forEach(function(elem) {
    let isMatching = !val || new RegExp(val, "gi").test(elem.textContent); // true или false
    anyMatch = anyMatch || isMatching; // (*)
    elem.closest("article").classList.toggle('hide', !isMatching);
  });
  noResult.classList.toggle("hide", anyMatch);
});

const sortArticles = (cont, order) => {
  const container = document.getElementById(cont);
  order.forEach((idx) => {
    let articleElement = container.querySelector("[data-custom-sort='" + idx + "']");
    articleElement.classList.remove("hide");
    container.appendChild(articleElement);
  });
};

document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("choose-cat")) {
    e.preventDefault()
    document.getElementById('elastic').value = '';
    sortArticles("game-items-cart", tgt.dataset.order.split(","))
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.elastic article.hide {
  display: none;
}

#sort>a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="elastic" class="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search Anything Here...">

<div id="sort">
  <a id="sort-best" class="choose-cat" data-order="3,1,4,2">best</a> |
  <a id="sort-default" class="choose-cat" data-order="1,2,3,4">default</a>
</div>

<div id="game-items-cart" class="elastic">
  <span id="no-result-id" class="no-result hide">no result</span>
  <article data-custom-sort="1">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">One</h3>
  </article>
  <article data-custom-sort="2">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Two</h3>
  </article>
  <article data-custom-sort="3">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Three</h3>
  </article>
  <article data-custom-sort="4">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Four</h3>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using jquery filter method
Here is the link of a demo, you can refer.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

Once you are get the filtered data, then perform sorting on that.

If you cannot use Jquery then no problem.
First thing which you mentioned in your question is "you cannot sort by category once you enter anything in the search bar." But when i tested your code and I added a new article "Four" then entered "o" in the search bar and tried to sort then it was sorting on the basis of category. Have a lookk in the snippet.

You wanted to remove hide while sorting, I have implemented a logic to remove it.
The snippet is updated with latest code, there is a slight modification in sortArticles function.

check if this works for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .elastic article.hide {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="elastic" class="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search Anything Here...">

    <div id="sort">
        <a id="sort-best" class="choose-cat" data-order="3,1,4,2">best</a> |
        <a id="sort-default" class="choose-cat" data-order="1,2,3,4">default</a>
    </div>

    <div id="game-items-cart" class="elastic">
        <span id="no-result-id" class="no-result hide">no result</span>
        <article data-custom-sort="1">
            <h3 class="card-hide-title">One</h3>
        </article>
        <article data-custom-sort="2">
            <h3 class="card-hide-title">Two</h3>
        </article>
        <article data-custom-sort="3">
            <h3 class="card-hide-title">Three</h3>
        </article>
        <article data-custom-sort="4">
            <h3 class="card-hide-title">Four</h3>
        </article>
    </div>

    <script>
        let noResult = document.querySelector("#no-result-id");
        document.querySelector('#elastic').addEventListener("input", function(){
            let val = this.value.trim();
            let items = document.querySelectorAll('.elastic article h3');
            if (!val) {
                noResult.classList.add("hide");
                return items.forEach(function _show_all(elem) {
                    elem.closest('article').classList.remove('hide');
                });
            }
            let anyMatch = false;
            items.forEach(function (elem) {
                let isMatching = new RegExp(val, "gi").test(elem.textContent); // true или false
                anyMatch = anyMatch || isMatching; // (*)
                elem.closest("article").classList.toggle('hide', !isMatching);
            });
            noResult.classList.toggle("hide", anyMatch);
        });

        const sortArticles = (cont, order) => {
            const container = document.getElementById(cont);
            order.forEach((idx) => {
                let articleElement = container.querySelector("[data-custom-sort='" + idx + "']");
                if(articleElement.classList.contains("hide")){
                    articleElement.classList.toggle("hide", false);
                }
                container.appendChild(articleElement);
            });
        };

        document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener("click", e => {
            const tgt = e.target;
            if (tgt.classList.contains("choose-cat")) {
                e.preventDefault()
                sortArticles("game-items-cart", tgt.dataset.order.split(","))
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: because jquery cannot be used in the project

Comment: Yes, you're right, everything works. But I need that when clicking on a category, the "hide" class is removed and **all** elements are sorted.

Comment: Clicking multiple times on `best` or `default` has interesting effect =)

Comment: @Anton, I tried it, no effect. What are you talking about? Are you saying that "four" comes first?

Comment: @Samalamadoit it is not to you, it is to Shivanshu. If you try to run the snippet in this answer, then do not enter into input, but press on 'best' several times. You will see that items are sorted in different way each time.

Comment: @Samalamadoit I think yes, but not today... And I have a question. You said: `How do I remove the hide class when I click on the sort button?` Well, if we can remove `hide` class, then what to do with search input box? Clear it if I click sort button? Otherwise it is not logical if all items seen but sorting is not empty.

Comment: @Samalamadoit why do you need `data-order="3,1,2"` attribute? This is because each sort mode has predefined sort order? So if you will have 5 elements, then you will add 5 number to `data-order`?

Comment: @Anton, Yes, this sets the sort order. This is normal.

Comment: @Samalamadoit don't you think that your search and sort are conflicting each other. Like if you search for "o", three doesn't contains "o", so it is hidden but if 3 is available in your sort-order then you have to show three also. Here, your sort is proving the search wrong.

Comment: @Anton, yes, but if by clicking on the sort button all the elements become visible, and the search field is cleared, then everything will be okay.